# Xilinx FPGA, error creating generated clock

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, artix-series-fpga

I just got a Digilent Basys 3 board (Artix-7 FPGA) and I am trying to create a program to transmit data over the UART-USB connection.  I wrote a module but when I tried to implement it I got a timing error.  I have been using the standard 100 Mhz clock which comes with the board.  I now think I need something slower like 50 Mhz.  I don't think I can change the standard clock since that is fixed at 100 Mhz by the board so I think I need to create a generated clock.  I added the following lines to my xdc file.

```
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W5 [get_ports clk]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports clk]
create_clock -period 10.000 -name sys_clk_pin -waveform {0.000 5.000} -add [get_ports clk]

create_generated_clock -divide_by 2 -source [get_ports clk] [get_ports clk2]
```

I then get the error.  Generated clock clk2 has not logical path from master clock sys_clk_pin.  Am I missing a step.  Do I need to do something more than create it in the XDC file?  Here is the header for my top level module.

```
module serial_emitter(
    output RsTx,
    input RsRx,
    input clk,
    input clk2,
    output [3:0] an,
    output [6:0] seg);
```

I want the slower clock to map to the clk2 input.

Comment: Why not use a clock divider component?

Comment: So I used the Clock Wizzard IP to create a generated clock which seems to work.  I guess I don't need to add the constraint to the XDC file in this case?

Comment: ```create_generated_clock``` instructions are nothing more than directives to the static timing analyser to describe what clocks are what. You actually need to **implement** the logic or primitives that produce the clock.

Comment: I think you should also review your UART module, because a normal UART can run with up to 250 MHz on 7-Series FPGA. When the timing analysis reports failing paths, have you check what's going wrong with these paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've constrained the clock for static timing analysis, but you never actually wrote the logic to divide a clock by two:

```
reg r_clk_div;
always @(posedge i_clk) begin

   r_clk_div  <=  !r_clk_div;

end

assign o_clk2 = r_clk_div;
```

This should synthesize to a DFF clocked by input clock, Q tied to D through an inverter, and then the Q output is your new clock. Your constraint tells the tools that you've generated this clock from an existing clock / resource and to treat it accordingly.

Note that I don't have a reset for this divider since I didn't see one in your module, but it may not be a bad idea to avoid temporary meta stability.

Apologies for typos, I'm on mobile.

Comment: Just wondering how do I add a reset.  Is it a signal that gets generated when the device starts?  How would I add that port to my top level module and add it to the XDC file?

Comment: I think you must have a reset somewhere in your design -- I bet the Digilent board has a reset wired up to a pin already. Think of it this way -- how do you make sure all your nice peripherals and registers you've written start up in the state you want?

Comment: Don't generate clocks this way. Use a DCM or PLL instead.

Comment: A DCM/PLL is the better way to generate a clock, agreed. They just aren't always available in a FPGA and this application seems simple enough that a simple DFF will do the job and be a bit more educational.